# react-dom.development.js:4312 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

It's my first time asking for help here (I usually find answers here without the need to post).

This is a very simple application, but I'm struggling with that. Whenever I click on the button to call one of the functions bellow, I'm presented with this error

```
index.tsx:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at handleIncrease (index.tsx:23:22)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:25)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:3)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:7)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:5)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:3)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:12
```

The functions are in the context file. they were supposed to be working, I guess. But It doenst!!

HELP!!

```
interface CoffeeContextProps {
  coffee: CartItem
}

export function Checkout({ coffee }: CoffeeContextProps) {

 const {changeCartItemsQuantity, removeCartItem} = useCart()
    const {cartItems} = useContext(CartContext);

 function handleDecrease() {
  changeCartItemsQuantity(coffee.id, 'decrease')
}

function handleIncrease() {
  console.log(coffee.id);
  
  changeCartItemsQuantity(coffee.id, 'increase')
  
}
function handleRemovedItem () {
  removeCartItem(coffee.id)
}
```

I've tried to change the type of the `coffee.id`.  I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: Check the type of CartItem?

Comment: It literally means that your `coffee` prop is `undefined`. How do you pass it? How do you assign its value before that?

Comment: CartItem interface declared in the context file: `export interface CartItem extends Coffee {
  quantity: number;
  }`. it was imported in the component file. The original Coffee interface : `export interface Coffee {
  id: string
  picture: string
  feature: string[]
  title: string
  description: string
  price: number
  quantity?: number
}`

Comment: I'm all set , guys! thatnk you for taking the time to help me. I decided to create a component for the card and import the types there.